# Gas limit and price in send raw transaction

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, nodejs

trying to compile a contract and then send it to the network.  The current error I'm getting is

```
Error: transaction underpriced
```

Here is my code for compiling the rawTx.  I'm on Ropsten, and the gas price is: 21000000000 and the gasLimit latest is: 4712388(from the console.logs)

```
const gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
console.log(gasPrice);
const gasPriceHex = web3.toHex(gasPrice);
var glimit = web3.eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit;
console.log(glimit);
gasLimitHex = web3.toHex(glimit);

nonce =  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1) ;
nonceHex = web3.toHex(nonce);

var payloadData = solidityFunction.data;


var rawTx = {
    nonce: nonceHex,
    gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
    gasLimit: gasLimitHex,
    to:contractAddress,
    from:account1,
    value: web3.toHex(web3.toWei('.01', 'ether')),
    data: payloadData
};
```

Comment: Your `gasLimit` is set to be the latest block's gas limit, don't use that. Try `web3.eth.estimateGas` and set `gas` of the rawTx. Also, shouldn't `to` be 0?

Comment: Thanks for the estimateGas solution.  I'm still getting the underpriced error though.  The to field is the contract address I'm trying to call and the payload data is the function bytecode

Answer (score 1):

no need hex data, web3 will deal with it.

```
var rawTx = {
    nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1),
    gasPrice: web3.eth.gasPrice;,
    gasLimit: web3.eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit,
    to:contractAddress,
    from:account1,
    value: 0.1,
    data: payloadData
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the nonce of some account, you should add 1 as the new nonce of rawTx.

### Example:

```
>>nonce =  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1) ;
>>nonceHex = web3.toHex(nonce);
```

I cannot find more data from the code of "payloadData", it is another way to make mistake.